# How to render the icon based on the prop using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to display the icon based on the prop named count.

What i am trying to do?
I have the Parent and Child components within child component i want to render the icon based on the count prop.

```
render = () => {
const count = 10; //got by http request and its value could be undefined, 0 or anything 
//above 0
return (
    <Wrapper>
        <LeftSide>
            <ContainerComponent>
                <ContentComponent>
                    items_count=10
                    icon_name='add'
                </ContentComponent>
           </ContainerComponent>
       </LeftSide>
       <RightSide>
           <ContainerComponent>
               <ContentComponent>
                   icon_name='delete'
               </ContentComponent>
           </ContainerComponent>
       </RightSide>
   </Wrapper>
```

)

```
const ContentComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({
  icon_name,
  count,
}) => {
    return (
        {condition1 && condition2 && 
            <firstdiv> 
               <seconddiv>
                   <Icon name={icon_name} />
               </seconddiv>
            </firstdiv>
        ))}
    )
}
```

Now here as you see the Icon component display add or delete icons based on the icon_name.

Now i want to add a check to icon add such that this icon should not be displayed when the count is < 1. 
so how do i change the above code to get the desired output.

i have tried adding a check with count < 1 like below but it doesnt work as i need meaning doesnt render both add and delete when value is greate than 1.

```
 return (
     {condition1 && condition2 && 
         {icon_name === 'add' && count && count < 1 ? return null : (
          <firstdiv> 
             <seconddiv>
                 <Icon name={icon_name} />
             </seconddiv>
         </firstdiv>
     ))}
```

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: It is strange that you use `condition1, condition2, firstdiv, seconddiv`, is this actual code or pseudo-code? Thanks

Comment: it is an example not the real code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need an additional nesting of the ifs. Maybe like this?

```
if(!condition1 || !condition2 ) {
    return null;
}
if(icon_name === 'add') {
    return count && count < 1 ? return null : (
       <firstdiv> 
          <seconddiv>
              <Icon name={icon_name} />
           </seconddiv>
      </firstdiv>
} else {
    return <firstdiv> 
          <seconddiv>
             <Icon name={icon_name} />
           </seconddiv>
      </firstdiv>
}
```

By separating the code like this, it makes it easier to follow and to add conditions.
You could also inline it this:

```
if(!condition1 || !condition2 ||(icon_name === 'add' && count && count < 1)) {
    return null;
}
return (
       <firstdiv> 
          <seconddiv>
              <Icon name={icon_name} />
           </seconddiv>
      </firstdiv>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this problem a bit differently. The show/hide of the icons seems to me to be the parent's responsibility - there's no need render the RightSide at all if it is just there to show an icon based on the count. That said, it isn't clear what `condition1` and `condition2` mean in your code, since these aren't passed in as props to your child component, so there might be some reason - maybe you can clarify what these are? And also whether `<firstdiv>` etc. are custom components.

```
// Further up
<ParentComponent count={ 10 } />

const ParentComponent: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ count }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <LeftSide>
        <ContainerComponent>
          <ContentComponent icon_name="add" />
        </ContainerComponent>
      </LeftSide>
      { count > 0 && (
        <RightSide>
            <ContainerComponent>
              <ContentComponent icon_name="delete" />
            </ContainerComponent>
        </RightSide>
       )}
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

const ContentComponent: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ icon_name }) => {
  return (
    <div className="whatever">
      <Icon name={ icon_name } />
    </div>
  )
}
```